# KVM control guest from host

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Virtualbox has a nice feature called [Guest control](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-guestcontrol) which through guest additions allows the host to execute commands inside a running guest. This can be useful in many ways such as automating deployment of software in the guest. Is there a way in KVM to execute commands in a running guest from the host system. I'm just interested in Linux hosts and guests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, kvm doesn't provide anything like that. But that's not really part of kvm's purpose. Any reason why you can't use ordinary methods for executing commands/deploying software on the guest such as `ssh` or even one of the configuration management systems like puppet/chef/whatever?

Comment: I'm facing a time shift issue with my KVM guests http://serverfault.com/questions/469598/kvm-guest-time-shift-on-host-reboot. I wanted to use a feature like this to do a work around to correct the time on the guest machines. So my need can't really be met with configuration management. I will probably use ssh in the end, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it without having to install ssh keys on all the guests far all the hosts. As this is an issue I'm facing on all my hosts and all their guests.

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh Solving the _actual_ problem is preferable to creating weird hacks like this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I completely agree. Thank you for answering that question I won't have to resort to any weird hacks after all.